# How to kill background processes on Samsung devices programmatically

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Some apps keep running in background after being closed.
I can see them in the device maintenance (battery).
I would like to close these apps programmatically (These apps are mine too, so I could modify them if needed).

I tried "killBackgroundProcesses", but it doesn't work. Actually, the app doesn't even show in the processes list when I execute "adb shell ps -A".
I also tried to close these apps differently, but they randomly appear in the "apps that drain battery" list.

How can I close them programmatically from my Android app?

Comment: try `adb shell ps` without -A

Answer (score 0):

You can get background processes pid with this command :

```
adb shell ps -A |grep BackgroundProcessesName |awk "{print $1}
```

and kill it :

```
adb shell kill pid
```

in one line command :

```
adb shell kill $(adb shell ps -A |grep BackgroundProcessesName |awk "{print $1})
```